# RSA secure private key inside exe file

Tags: java, c#, encryption, rsa

I am creating `C#`,`Java` desktop application (exe), I need to encrypt user password and license related information so i have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850030/aes-256-encryption-public-and-private-key-how-can-i-generate-and-use-it-net). But the problem is if i use RSA public/private key encryption then i will need both the keys in the exe file to keep user and license information changeable, but if someone reverse engineers the .exe file and gets the private key then data will be compromised.

How can i secure my private key in the .exe file? Is there any other technique to save private key from reverse engineering?

There is some Obfuscate tool which can stop reverse engineering but still private key will be visible and using such tool is very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hashing function for user passwords (like SHA) and do never store a private key on the users system. For licensing information, generate RSA signed license data and send it to the user via E-Mail or any other way, your application will only need the public key of your licensing server to validate the license data.

Comment: i am using license file and when application start, read and validate and write the current timestamp as in encrypted format in the same file so that why i need private key.

Comment: There is no solution for this, your private key should never be exposed. Whenever your private key is exposed, the security of your product is totally gone.

Comment: i got it point about username and password but how can i handle license ? as when user start the application i keep track on last used date so  user can not play with system date. so thats why i need to encrypt this as well, so i am writing this data in same license file. Can you provide me your idea how to handle this data ?

Comment: Write the creation time into the license file and keep track of your applications files, if any databases or other files you regurarily write to seem to be written to in the future, the system clock has been tempered with.

Comment: i didnt understand the point, can you please explain in detail.

Comment: Just get the last modified time of some key files of your application and check them for plausibility.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, there is no technique to save the private key from reverse engineering. There is no obfuscation tool which can stop reverse engineering of the private key. You cannot secure the private key in the executable file.

Don't take my word for it. Search for examples of hacked systems which have had their private key reversed engineered. There are plenty. I just found this example: http://goodenoughsecurity.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-ps3-lv0-key-was-probably-hacked.html

Answer (score -3):

1. I would use a server to encrypt. Then I can just make a post request to the server and send the key, or validate the key, or delete the key for example. ERROR: The app is standalone.
2. Pack your application. For example in UPX. ERROR: Unpackable.
3. Store keys in the registry. ERROR: Unsecure.
   You'll need to store it on a server

Comment: its a standalone desktop application which can run without internet same a anti virus application. No server

Comment: @VarunJain Running a server on your user's computer is an option too, but i'll edit my answer.

Comment: anyway if i use local server then till someone can reverse engineering that server file which is giving private key

Comment: @VarunJain True. Added other option.

Comment: @VarunJain Sorry. I gave a bad answer. Edited again.

Comment: Storing the keys inside the registry is not a secure option as well. A private key for licensing purposes should never be stored anywhere on a users system!

Comment: @jonas.koeritz Yeah. So Varun will need to store it on a server.

Comment: here is no option for server.