# Is RSACryptoServiceProvider working correctly?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, implementation

I'm using .NET's implementation of RSA, and two things looked odd to me.  I'd like to confirm that it's operating properly.

#### Background

Using [`System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) with 2048-bit keyword size to perform asymmetric encryption/decrpytion, initially following the example in [this question, "AES 256 Encryption: public and private key how can I generate and use it .net"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850030/aes-256-encryption-public-and-private-key-how-can-i-generate-and-use-it-net).

As a first implementation, this seems to work:

```
public const int  CSPPARAMETERS_FLAG = 1;      // Specifies RSA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148034(v=vs.110).aspx
public const bool USE_OAEP_PADDING   = false;
public const int  KEYWORD_SIZE       = 2048;

public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] publicKey, byte[] dataToEncrypt)
{
    var cspParameters = new System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters(CSPPARAMETERS_FLAG);
    byte[] encryptedData = null;

    using (var rsaProvider = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters))
    {
        try
        {
            rsaProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(publicKey);
            encryptedData = rsaProvider.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, USE_OAEP_PADDING);
        }
        finally
        {
            rsaProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            rsaProvider.Clear();
        }
    }
    return encryptedData;
}

public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] privateKey, byte[] dataToDecrypt)
{
    var cspParameters = new System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters(CSPPARAMETERS_FLAG);
    byte[] encryptedData = null;

    using (var rsaProvider = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters))
    {
        try
        {
            rsaProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(privateKey);
            encryptedData = rsaProvider.Decrypt(dataToDecrypt, USE_OAEP_PADDING);
        }
        finally
        {
            rsaProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            rsaProvider.Clear();
        }
    }

    return encryptedData;
}
```

After looking into these methods a bit more, it seems that the public key that I've been generating as from [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850030/aes-256-encryption-public-and-private-key-how-can-i-generate-and-use-it-net) seemed to have a lot of very predictable data at its start, and it was 276-bytes long.

Apparently [`rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(bool includePrivateParameters)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.exportcspblob(v=vs.110).aspx) is a functional alternative to [`rsaProvider.ExportParameters(bool includePrivateParameters)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.exportparameters(v=vs.110).aspx); the main difference is that the blob is already serialized as a `byte[]` while the other emits the object version, [`RSAParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Two observations about the methods:

1. The `.Exponent` is always `0x010001`$=65537$.
2. The exported blobs contain 17 extra bytes versus the serialized typed versions.

   - `rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob()`:

     - Public key is 276 bytes.
     - Private key is 1172 bytes.
   - `RSAParameters`:

     - Public key is 259 bytes.

       - `.Exponent.Length =   3`
       - `.Modulus .Length = 256`
     - Private key is 1155 bytes.

       - `.D       .Length = 256`
       - `.DP      .Length = 128`
       - `.DQ      .Length = 128`
       - `.Exponent.Length =   3`
       - `.InverseQ.Length = 128`
       - `.Modulus .Length = 256`
       - `.P       .Length = 128`
       - `.Q       .Length = 128`
   - The extra 17 bytes appear to be at the header of the binary blob.

### Concerns

From this, two concerns:

1. Is it okay for the exponent to not be random?

   - If the exponent is defined as a constant, then it'd seem like that's another 3 bytes I could shave off the serialization?
   - Another question, [Should RSA public exponent be only in {3, 5, 17, 257 or 65537} due to security considerations?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c), seems to suggest that $\left{3, 5, 17, 257, 65537\right}$ are all common values for the exponent, so `0x101`$=65537$ seems reasonable if it's true that there's no harm in always using the same constant exponent.
2. Are the 17 extra bytes an information leak?

   - Do they represent the option parameters like key length and method?
   - Is it a good idea to be transmitting option parameter information when I already know that both the sender and receiver are using the same, hard-coded method?

### Question

Is [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)'s behavior a cause for concern, or are these things normal?

### Update 1

In [Should RSA public exponent be only in {3, 5, 17, 257 or 65537} due to security considerations?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c), the accepted answer starts off by noting:

> There is no known weakness for any short or long public exponent for RSA, as long as the public exponent is "correct" (i.e. relatively prime to p-1 for all primes p which divide the modulus).

If this is so, then I'd guess that the apparently-constant exponent of `0x010001`$=65537$ is sufficient as long as it's relatively prime to $p-1$.  So, presumably the .NET implementation of RSA checks for this condition.

But then what does `RSACryptoServiceProvider` do if that condition isn't satisfied?  If it selects a different exponent, then that'd seem to leak information about $p$ whenever the exponent isn't `0x010001`.  Or, if a different key is selected, then it'd seem like we can just assume that the exponent is always `0x010001` and omit it from the serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything reported is normal, and non-alarming.

It is perfectly OK for the public exponent *e* to be short and non-random. *e* = 2<sup>16</sup>+1 = 65537 = 0x010001 is common and safe. Some authorities mandate it (or some range including it). Using it (or/and something significantly larger than the bit size of the public modulus) gives some protection against some of the worst RSA paddings.

No, the 17 extra bytes in the public key are unlikely to be an information leak; they more likely are a header part of the data format chosen for an RSA public key by the software you use. My guess is that you are encountering the MS-specific format detailed in this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41874/555) (perhaps, within endianness), which also uses precisely 276 bytes for an RSA public key with a 2048-bit public modulus. In that case, you should find that the extra bytes are always the same (thus they demonstrably leak nothing). And there are countless more subtle ways to leak information about the private key, like in the public modulus itself.

Many RSA key generators used in practice, including I guess `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, first choose *e*, then somewhat avoid generating primes *p* such that gcd(*e*, *p*-1) ≠ 1. Since *e* = 65537 is prime, it is enough that ( *p* % *e* ) ≠ 1, and this is easily checked, or otherwise insured by the process generating *p*.